# Empty assistant editor in xcode interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm following a [walkthrough on designing mac apps using xamarin and c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac) and at one point the tutorial hands off to xcode's interface builder for creating the UI. I've not used xcode's interface builder before so this is all new to me.

I can see in the tutorial that the version of xcode they're using is different (older) than the one I have, so the tools look a bit different but seem to work the same.

At one point I'm asked to open the Assistant Editor so that I can have a split of the interface builder and the code. According to the tutorial after opening the assistant editor I should see a file open automatically for me:

[image: What I should see]

But when I open the assistant editor in the interface builder not only do I not get my file automatically selected for me, but I can't go to the drop down menu to navigate to it manually.

[image: blank assistant editor]

I know the file in question `ViewController.h` exists and xcode is aware of it because I can see it in the main code editor window:

[image: I SEE YOU!!!!]

But for some reason I can't get it in the assistant editor.

I wouldn't be surprised if this is just due to me not clicking on the right thing or opening the assistant editor incorrectly, but I can't seem to figure out or find an answer as to how I *should* be opening it.

Any help?

## Workaround

So I haven't figured out how to fix the issue, but I did figure out a work around.

I figured that if the assistant editor was just a quick window to the code so you can control drag from the UI Editor to the code then I could probably do the same from the UI Editor window to the actual editor window.

[image: workaround]

And it works. It's a bit cumbersome but at least it gets me through. If someone has the answer I'm still happy to give a checkmark :)